# change account authenticate method from username to email

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-jwt

I want to change login method from **username** to **email**.

urls.py

```
from rest_framework_jwt.views import obtain_jwt_token,refresh_jwt_token

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', obtain_jwt_token),
    url(r'^tokenRefresh/', refresh_jwt_token)
]
```

setting.py

```
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
```

I have used above solution but not working for me. can you please help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `django-allauth` has nothing to do with `django-rest-framework-jwt`. The settings you've set inside `settings.py` was belong the `django-allauth` so if you want to use those settings, then you should use `django-allauth` views.

With `django-rest-framework-jwt` views, I've taken a look on `obtain_jwt_token` view and I've seen that they're using `get_user_model().USERNAME_FIELD` to get the username field.

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

def get_username_field():
    try:
        username_field = get_user_model().USERNAME_FIELD
    except AttributeError:
        username_field = 'username'

    return username_field
```

So if you want to change username field to another one, you could create a custom `User` model and then set the value for `USERNAME_FIELD` to `email` to allow user to login via `email` instead of `username`. Like so:

**app_name/models.py**

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class User(AbstractUser):
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

and on your **settings.py:**

```py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app_name.User'
```